# Conceptual Doubt from the topic Momentum and Center of Mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, momentum

Well, recently I was solving a question where two bodies were acted upon by forces equal in magnitude and same in direction(Net force on system was zero), well the question was pretty simple, where do the two bodies collide? I knew the answer as at the COM of system of the two bodies, as my teacher had said so, but I dont exactly understand why does this happen? and does this statement hold true everywhere?

Comment: Have you considered modeling this quantitatively?

Comment: I haven't , I myself am looking for a proof to the statement, couldnt find it in the books I refer.

Comment: The location of the contact is given by the geometry as the point in space where bodies start to overlap. In some cases, there is more than one point.

Comment: @JAlex could you please be more precise and clear with the statement please? and also what cases could have more than a point?

Comment: Consider an edge contacting another edge, or a plane. Most complex to handle is a plane to plane contact where multiple contact points exist each with their own contact force.

Comment: I think youve misunderstood the question. the body is a point mass and a rigid body. you dont have to consider such kind of contacts.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a mathematical approach,

We know that the Center of Mass of the two particles is given by:
$$R_C= \frac{ M_1 r_1 + M_2 r_2}{M1+M2}$$

Now for these particles to end up at the same location(collide), we can say that $r_1=r_2=r$.

The center of mass of a system is fixed. It does not move unless an external force acts on it. So it is still fixed at $R_C$.

So, we can see from substituting the values of $r_1$ and $r_2$ that r comes out to be $R_C$, which was the location of the center of mass.

PS: If you are familiar with the concept of angular momentum and gravitation and want to try to gain more conceptual clarity I would very highly recommend the below question.
[image]

Comment: Jee aspirant huh?

Comment: Well dude, my question was  a bit different I'll upload the question Ive been asking bout , soon.

Answer (score 1):

The contact forces are not required to go through the combined COM. Since the net load is zero, its location does not affect the nature of the problem.

The simplest situation to consider is a single contact point where two equal and opposite forces act, along the contact normal $\hat{n}$.

[image: fig1]

Often in contact modeling we consider an exchange in momentum, instead of forces, and the effect this has on the motion of the two bodies.

Consider an impulse of magnitude $J$ acting along $\hat{n}$ acting on body **`[2]`** and along $-\hat{n}$ on body **`[1]`**. The center of mass of each body is described relative to the contact point.

We describe the *step* in  translational motion of each body with the following equations of motion

$$ \begin{aligned}
 m_1 \Delta \vec{v}_1 & = -\hat{n} J \\
 m_2 \Delta \vec{v}_2 & = +\hat{n} J \\
\end{aligned} \tag{1}$$

where $\vec{v}_i$  is the velocity at the center of mass, and $m_i$ is each mass measure.

The change in rotational motion is given by the following equations of motion

$$ \begin{aligned}
 \mathrm{I}_1 \Delta \vec{\omega}_1 & = (- \hat{n} J) \times \vec{c}_1 \\
 \mathrm{I}_2 \Delta \vec{\omega}_2 & = (+ \hat{n} J) \times \vec{c}_2 \\
\end{aligned} \tag{2}$$

Here $\mathrm{I}_i$ is the mass moment of inertia tensor of each body at the center of mass and $\vec{\omega}_i$ the rotational velocity of each body.

Finally, the contact condition is a relationship between the relative speed of each body at the contact point along the contact normal.

$$ (u_{2}^\text{after} - u_{1}^\text{after}) = - \epsilon\; ( u_{2}^\text{before} - u_{1}^\text{before})  \tag{3}$$

where $\epsilon$ is the coefficient of restitution.

Use standard velocity transformations describe the speed components.

$$ \begin{aligned}
  u_1^\text{before} & =  \hat{n} \cdot \left( \vec{v}_1 + \vec{c}_1 \times \vec{\omega}_1 \right) \\  
  u_2^\text{before} & =  \hat{n} \cdot \left( \vec{v}_2 + \vec{c}_2 \times \vec{\omega}_2 \right) \\
  u_1^\text{after} & =  \hat{n} \cdot \left( \vec{v}_1 + \Delta \vec{v}_1 + \vec{c}_1 \times ( \vec{\omega}_1 + \Delta \vec{\omega}_1) \right) \\  
  u_2^\text{after} & =  \hat{n} \cdot \left( \vec{v}_2 + \Delta \vec{v}_2 + \vec{c}_2 \times ( \vec{\omega}_2 + \Delta \vec{\omega}_2) \right) \\
\end{aligned} \tag{4}$$

Plug (1) and (2) into (4) and then into (3) to come up with a single scalar equation  in terms of $J$.

**References**

1. [An Introduction to Physically Based Modeling:
   Rigid Body Simulation II—Nonpenetration
   Constraints](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ebaraff/sigcourse/notesd2.pdf)